# Does Junior perceive he is being condescended to/not taken seriously as boss?

Tags: the-sopranos

I have been watching old clips and it is explicitly stated that Tony gave his uncle the boss position to deflect attention from himself. There is more than one time when it seems pretty clear that people in general know this. Johnny Sack in one scene seems to give Junior a compliment, saying something like, If there are any flies on you, they are paying rent; but this compliment is not really merited.

There are also times when Junior gets angry that people ask Tony's opinion in front of him but he also settles down -- like he also knows that he is not really boss but the title alone, fake or not, is enough for him (until I guess he actually gets into legal troubles because of it).

So is Junior so out of it that he really believes he is running things (and he does manage to get people killed, so that is significant) or does he know what Tony has done to him?

I would like to emphasize that I am interested in knowing in general just how senile he was supposed to be. I would guess in real life a man of that age might remain the head of a family but to ascend to that position probably never would happen.

Comment: Are answers allowed to go into future / all seasons, where are you up to exactly?  Junior's legal and health status changes significantly through the show - both having an impact on whether he understands his true status in the organization.

Comment: sure. interested in all seasons and future.